# Pyqgis: Writing automated unit tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgis

I implemented some unit tests (with `unittest`) for a qgis3+ plugin, and I would like to run those tests programmatically.
Currently, I launch those  tests directly from the QGis UI, but that prevent me from using some CI tool like Travis or Gitlab-CI...

I already found this topic, but it is outdated and most of the links are already dead: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71206/writing-automated-tests-for-qgis-plugins?rq=1

[This page](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/01/04/writing-unit-tests-for-qgis-python-plugins/) was also greatly detailed, but a note from 2017 said it to be obsolete.

Does someone know about a way to achieve this, or at least about some ressource or documentation on the subject?

Comment: Maybe an explanation about the downvote?